# How to change BCD internal drive letter assignment

Tags: drive-letter, bcd

As you know, the following values can be changed by using BCDEDIT:

device partition=E:
osdevice partition=E:

But question is that how did BCD name a certain volume (e.g. E: above) and how can it be corrected? Depending on windows installation method, this drive letter can differ for the same partition. Then, is there a document for BCD explaining about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to open a command prompt, either in Automatic Repair, or in WinPE. Assign drive letters to the System partition (e.g. D:) and to the OS/Windows partition assign the letter (C:). Then used BOOTREC to rebuild the BCD store.

- DISKPART
- lis dis (identify OS harddrive)
- sel dis 0 lis par (identify above System and OS partitions)
- sel par 1 (e.g. System)
- assign letter=D
- sel par 3 (e.g. OS/Windows)
- assign letter=C
- exit

then

- BOOTREC /FIXBOOT (should say "Successful")
- BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD (Should find C:\WINDOWS - choose Y option to add to the boot store)

Reboot the system and hopefully it should start.

Comment: Thank you very very much, the above answer solved the problem!
Although "BOOTREC /FIXBOOT" isn't required for this problem.